# eclipse formatter not working

Tags: eclipse, formatter

I have created a custom java code style formatter.
But when I try to use source->format it is not formatting the files.
Also I tried working with source->Clean Up , where I created a custom clean up and applied Format Source Code option. But still the files are not being formatted.

Sometimes eclipse shows progress of formatting, but if I check the code only few files (that also xml) get changed.

Edit - 
I have tried clicking and formatting from root project as well as source folder.
Also the source folder is in build path.

I checked the error log and found following exception -

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.Scribe.getNewLineString(Scribe.java:1137)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.Scribe.getEmptyLines(Scribe.java:1062)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.Scribe.printEmptyLines(Scribe.java:3050)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.Scribe.preserveEmptyLines(Scribe.java:1584)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.Scribe.printComment(Scribe.java:2584)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.Scribe.printComment(Scribe.java:2414)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.CodeFormatterVisitor.format(CodeFormatterVisitor.java:714)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.CodeFormatterVisitor.visit(CodeFormatterVisitor.java:3294)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.traverse(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:679)
```

**Edit 2**
Found the root cause. It is happening due to a blank line and commented import statement-

```
import org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator;
import org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidatorConfiguration;

//import javax.validation.*;
import javax.validation.Configuration;
```

Comment: look for suspicious error messages clicking on help->about eclipse->installation details->configuration->view error log

Comment: Are you formatting Java source files located in a `Java Project`s `Source Folder`(s) according to the project `Java Build Path`?

Answer (score 3):

Check for syntax errors, such as unbalance braces.  This was the problem in my case.  The formatter apparently punts if such errors are present.